# Dimensiones relativas de un botón dinámico en java para diferentes resoluciones

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema al crear las dimensiones relativas válidas para diferentes resoluciones de botones dinámicos en java. Parto de la resolución de pantalla de cada dispositivo donde se ejecute y sin embargo las medidas aparecen más grandes en los dispositivos con menor resolución. Para averiguar la resolución, pongo el siguiente código:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) Actividad1.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (windowManager != null) {
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    }
    int ancho = metrics.widthPixels;
    int alto = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Y después, para la dimensión del botón:

```
    mi_botón.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ancho/5, 13*ancho/100));
```

¿Podrían echarme una mano?

Comment: Tu código tiene buena pinta. Te diría que debuguearas para comprobar que alto y ancho obtienes en cada resolucion y así determinar si te cuadran los tamaños. También comprueba que el layout del padre no tenga alguna propiedad que pueda interferir con el tamaño del botón, como paddings, etc

Comment: Gracias por la apreciación que haces de mi código. He tardado en responder porque, desde que creo que todo depende de la resolución con que defina los Emuladores de los distintos tipos de dispositivos para ver si mi aplicación funciona en todas la resoluciones, he estado investigando sobre esto. Seguiré ahora con este problema de definir las resoluciones de Emuladores correctas para los distintos tipos de dispositivos.